# Chilean citizen travelling to Europe (part 2: immigration inspection)

Tags: schengen, uk, customs-and-immigration, chile

I'm a first-time traveller with a lot of questions. I've never been outside Chile.

As a Chilean citizen, I don't need visas for UK or Schengen area. I'll be staying in UK, Austria, Czech Republic and Hungary.

I have all the necessary documentation (just in case). Fresh, pretty passport issued in February, travel insurance (I got it for free because I used my Gold Mastercard to pay for the tickets), enough funds (bills, credit cards -international Mastercard, American Express and Visa cards, issued in Chile- and a debit Visa card), and all my tickets are already printed (planes, trains and... *automobiles*. Just kidding! Planes, trains and buses). I also made the necessary reservations through Airbnb.

Do the border offices check that? What should I expect, considering my nationality? Do I have to bring something else?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't know whether Chilean citizens receive more scrutiny than US citizens, but I can tell you that US citizens are generally not asked for very much detail, or to prove return travel, or financial means, or insurance.  They generally get a question or a few about the purpose of the trip and then a stamp in the passport.  The UK tends to give a bit more scrutiny than most Schengen countries do, however.

Comment: I've been watching **UK border force** (to improve my English too), but it seems to focus primarily in Indian or Middle Easterners, or people requiring a visa.

Comment: There are, however, examples on that show of even US citizens being bounced (usually because they're planning to work in a way that they thought was allowed as a visitor, but wasn't), and I know a US citizen who was bounced in the late 90s because she showed up with too much luggage for a brief visit (and indeed she was planning to study without a proper visa, and she is, in her own words, "a really bad liar").

Comment: I am inclined to believe a Chilean **on average** will be scrutinized a bit more intensely than an American just because of economics.

Answer (score 2):

The majority of people who travel within a visa-free zone directly go through the border control without having to answer more than few questions (this is coming strictly from personal experience, I will search for some actual numbers and add them to the answer). Whether you will fall under more scrutiny is something that no one here will be able to answer as it depends strictly on your personal circumstances, but it is highly recommended to carry all required documents (the same [needed for visitors visa application](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/documents-you-must-provide)) with you for that eventuality. You are already planning to do that.

There is one thing you can do to have peace of mind at the border crossing - apply for visitors visa before you travel. Having that will mean that your situation was already assessed and will make you even less likely to have any problems with border control than an average citizen from Chile.

Comment: IIRC while the UK offers the option for visa-exempt nationals to get a visa anyway Schengen doesn't.